# I need to write a recursive function that prints 2**n as well as 2**(n-1) and 2**(n-2) etc. until 2**0. Outputs as one single sum currently

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def pow2(n):

    if n<=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2**n + pow2(n-1)

num = int(raw_input('Enter number: '))

print pow2(num)
```

Currently an input of 3 would output 15, which is the sum of 8+4+2+1. I would like to output all of these numbers separately (still without loops) as: 1 2 4 8 instead of 15. I understand how my current code is leading to the output that it does, but I have no idea how to separate the outputs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly are you asking for? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: Hi, so currently an input of 3 would output of 15, which is the sum of 8+4+2+1.  I would like to output all of these numbers separately (still without loops) as:
1
2
4
8
instead of 15.
i understand how my current code is leading to the output that it does, but i have no idea how to separate the outputs.

Comment: In the future, please add additional information directly to your question by editing rather than leaving comments.  (I'll do it for you this time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def pow2(n):
    print 2**n
    if n<=0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2**n + pow2(n-1)
```

if all you need to do is print it ...

or

if you need to return a list

```
def pow2(n):
    if n<=0:
        return [1]
    else:
        return [2**n] + pow2(n-1)
```

Comment: it doesnt ... its still returning the sum ... Ill i told it to do was print at each step ...

Comment: this answer will clearly produce what OP asked (+1).

Comment: The edited answer actually does not produce what i have specified, but the original answer was perfect.  I still am a little foggy on why I must print one statement and return the next with the else statement, but the code works nonetheless, so thank you Joran.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using list comprehensions:

```
def pow2(n):
    return([2**x for x in range(n+1)])

num = int(raw_input('Enter number: '))
for i in pow2(num):
    print(i)
```

Or something along those lines. It's technically not recursive but this way you will only need to call the method once.

If you need the larger number printed first you can use:

```
for i in sorted(pow2(num), reverse=True):
    print(i)
```